# Can moving fields from sandbox to production using change sets also make them visible for all profiles?

Tags: change-set, configuration

I am moving few custom fields from sandbox to production using changesets. 
Everytime i do this i need to go to each field and make them visible..

Is there a way i can say these have to be visible to all the profiles?

Maybe i am missing something elementary out here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you migrate the Profile metadata with the custom fields all FLS security data should be transferred along.

Comment: We probably need to be careful if the sandbox is not recently updated, then the chance of erasing the changes in production for the profiles might be lost. Is there a way to specifically move profile data only for these objects.. i guess No

Comment: I don't think you can move just the profile metadata for those objects. I agree you have to be careful deploying profiles, it's something I've always avoid due to how easily they get out of alignment between production/sandbox/source control